# localhost not working(apache2,ubuntu12.04). but showing "it works" page

Tags: 12.04, apache2

I am running apache2 on ubuntu linux. I dont know what is the reason but unable to access my localsite which is placed on var/www/xyz. xyz is the site root folder here. when I try only localhost it is showing **"It works**". but If I try with the site like **localhost/xyz**.It is showing the following error. It was worked fine till yesterday, but today I got this problem.

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

could anybody please help me in this regard.

I tried restarting I got this error

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check the apache error logs in /var/log/apache2 and tell us what it says so you can get some help!

Comment: ::1 - - [28/Jan/2013:10:40:04 +0530] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)". This is what it contains in the first line

Comment: Copy the relevant information from the error.log file in that directory. You might see something like `[Mon Jan 28 10:46:00 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down`

Comment: Yes it is there. What should I do now.
[Mon Jan 28 19:25:45 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down

Comment: @djthoms: Will you please tell me what to do

Comment: paste your log file on something like [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/) so we can see the file in its entirety. You want to isolate the problem. Hence `Action 'start' failed. The Apache error log may have more information.` There is a reason why apache won't start and it will be in the `error.log` file

Comment: http://pastebin.com/vnKZngGU. It is where I pasted the log please check and let me know what the heck

Comment: @djthoms: do u see anything useful, resolvable issue with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the issue..! 
It was due to, some other process using the same port 80. so it was unable to run. I found out process and killed and restarted the apache server.

It is working now.

Comment: Please mark this as accpted answer, when its possible.